# jQuery .hide() only working half the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might look very obvious to some people, but I really could not figure out why something like this might be happening, so I'm looking for any help possible!

I have expanding rows, and each row should expand to show its details when clicked on, or when next button is pressed. They show and hide properly when clicked, but I cannot get it to work when next button is pressed.

This is the .js part:

```
var main = function() {

var curQuantity1 = 0;
var curQuantity2 = 0;
var curQuantity3 = 0;

$('.article').click( function() {
    $('.description').hide();
    $('.article').removeClass('current');
    $(this).children('.description').show();
    $(this).addClass('current');
});

$(".next1").click( function() {
    if (curQuantity1 + curQuantity2 + curQuantity3 == 3){
        console.log("Next clicked");

        var currentArticle = $('.current');
        var nextArticle = currentArticle.next();

        currentArticle.removeClass('current');
        nextArticle.addClass('current');

        $('.description').hide();
        $('.current').children('.description').show();
    } else {
        alert("총 3통을 골라주세요");
    }
});
...//code here takes care of updating curQuantity so they can add upto 3
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

I think pasting html code here might make it too long, but will do so if needed.

I am vaguely guessing that child might not be allowed to modify its parent class, but I could not find a way around it.

Thank you in advance for any help! I was getting stumped for the whole day :(

Comment: There aren't any limitations around adding/removing classes. Perhaps try and re-create your issue using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that's the easiest way for us to help you out.

Comment: The Next button only goes to the next element when `curQuantity1 + curQuantity2 + curQuantity3 == 3`. But they're all set to 0, so the total is 0, and you just do the alert.

Comment: @Barmar oh I change the curQuantity in the ... section when buttons are pressed - the log "Next clicked" prints out safely ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.next1` is inside `.article`, when you click on the Next button, the click is also being sent to the article that contains it, because of event bubbling. So first the `.next1` click handler is revealing the next item, then the `.article` click reveals the old article. The solution is to use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling out:

```
$(".next1").click( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (curQuantity1 + curQuantity2 + curQuantity3 == 3){
        console.log("Next clicked");

        var currentArticle = $('.current');
        var nextArticle = currentArticle.next();

        currentArticle.removeClass('current');
        nextArticle.addClass('current');

        $('.description').hide();
        $('.current').children('.description').show();
    } else {
        alert("총 3통을 골라주세요");
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh so that was the problem! Thank you Barmar for such a nice explanation - helped me get a little better today! For anyone with the same issue - it works perfectly!

Comment: The Javascript debugger is your friend, learn to use it. I just single-stepped through your code, saw that it was moving to the next item, then moving back.